# Ms Access VBA run select query without opening

Tags: ms-access, select, vba, ms-access-2013

Is there any way to run a query using VBA without is opening? Currently the code I'm using is:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryAvailableCarpenters" 'Sorts the carpenters according to their jobs
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "qryAvailableCarpenters"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPermanentCarpenters" 'Sorts the supervising carpenters according to their number of supervisions
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "qryPermanentCarpenters"
DoCmd.RefreshRecord 'Enables the changes in sorting to be reflected in the combo box
```

This works but you still see a flash of the queries opening then closing. Is there a way I can change that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `currentdb.execute "qryAvailableCarpenters"`

Why are you doing this though? You should simply be able to specify an `ORDER BY` clause whenever you access the data. You order it however you wish when you retrieve the data, whether it be for form, report, or datasheet.